# Return Youtube video URL from keyword search with Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, parsing, youtube, discord

Alright , so I'm making a bot in Discord for my server, and something I wanted to implement is a youtube command.
I've been searching all over and looking in the Youtube API and all I can find is their search for what seems like a browser

I'm using nodejs to run it off of my laptop, and my bot runs off of discord.js
I have a similar command that does a MAL and a Urban Dictionary search, but I've found nothing and have no idea how to do the same with youtube

I used to have a command for a python bot that was able to due this, and I've seen other Discord bots able to do it as well, so I know it's obviously possible

Basically what I'm saying is I need to be able to search for and return a youtube video URL (the first search result) from a string of search terms so the usage would look like

```
>>youtube Tunak Tunak Tun
```

Would return 
`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vTIIMJ9tUc8` , which is the first search result for that keyword(s)

EDIT:
I've found the python command that would do this, but have nigh the skills nor the confidence to try to translate this to JavaScript

```
elif prefix and cmd=="youtube" and len(args) > 0:
        try:
            yword=args.replace(" ","_")
            ydata= urlreq.urlopen("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?vq="+yword+"&racy=include&orderby=relevance&max-results=1")
            yread= str(ydata.read())
            if "<openSearch:totalResults>0</openSearch:totalResults>" in yread:
                room.message("I got nothin' for ya by the name of "+args)
            else:
                trash , yclean=yread.split("<media:player url='http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=",1)
                yclean , trash=yclean.split("&amp;",1)
                room.message("http://http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+yclean,True)
        except:
            room.message("Somethin ain't right")
```

EDIT2 (Apologies for length) : Alright! I've found something that's gotten me a lot closer!
https://www.npmjs.com/package/youtube-search
  
I've got a command in my bot now that goes something like this:

```
if (commandIs("yt" , message)){
  search(args.join(' ').substring(4), opts, function(err, results) {
    if(err) return console.log(err);
  message.channel.sendMessage(results);
  console.log(results);
  });
}
```

So now when I enter `>>yt Tunak Tunak Tun` I get

```
[ { id: 'vTIIMJ9tUc8',
link: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vTIIMJ9tUc8',
kind: 'youtube#video',
publishedAt: '2014-03-21T07:00:01.000Z',
channelId: 'UC3MLnJtqc_phABBriLRhtgQ',
channelTitle: 'SonyMusicIndiaVEVO',
title: 'Daler Mehndi - Tunak Tunak Tun Video',
description: 'Presenting \'Tunak Tunak Tun\' music video sung by the talented Daler Mehndi Song Name - Tunak Tunak Tun Album - Tunak Tunak Tun Singer - Daler Mehndi ...',
thumbnails: { default: [Object], medium: [Object], high: [Object] } } ]
```

in the console and `[object Object]` in the discord channel.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeTFN.png

So the problem now is I have the link in my reach, but I can not get it to return **JUST** the link, and I've no idea how to pull it out of that mess.

Comment: Try console.log(results.link)

Comment: @jonofan undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your results object is a `JSON` string. This essentially means that it is a string representation of a javascript object. You can parse this into an object by using [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

```
var objResults = JSON.parse(results);
console.log(objResults);
console.log(objResults.link);
```

**EDIT**

Failed to notice that your result is actually an array. You just need to access it like this: `console.log(results[0].link)`. Shouldn't need to `JSON.parse()`

Comment: I end up gettting http://pastebin.com/yUr2Jy3 as a result.
I don't even know what it's nipping about now.

This is how and where I entered your snippet http://pastebin.com/qBiRhWXj

Comment: @Paraxo the first pastebin link is broken, so can't see your error, only your code.

Comment: @Paraxo have updated this answer, you shouldn't actually need to parse that. Just access it like an array.

Comment: This worked, but so you know what the error was trying to parse it
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: @Paraxo you can only parse a JSON string, not an object. The fact that you were getting an error is what prompted me to go and re-examine your original console output. :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's another approach that is working for me, using the google javascript API. Once again, the SO snippet doesn't run it, so [I'll link you to the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/u9frfosk/2/)

This method requires you to [setup a google API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#key), then [enable youtube API access.](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube/overview?project=everything-1387&duration=PT1H)

I've removed my google API key from the fiddle, so you'll need to set that up. I can PM you mine if you want to test first though.

```js
var apiKey = null //put your API key here

function search() {
 var searchTerm = $('#txtSearch').val()
 
  gapi.client.init({
    'apiKey': apiKey, 
    'discoveryDocs': ['https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest']
  }).then(function() {
    return gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
      q: searchTerm,
      part: 'snippet'
    });
  }).then(function(response) {
   var searchResult = response.result;
    $('#search-results').append(JSON.stringify(searchResult, null, 4))
   console.log(searchResult.items[0])
    var firstVideo = searchResult.items[0]
    firstVideo.url = `https://youtube.com/watch?v=${firstVideo.id.videoId}`
    $('#first-video').text(firstVideo.url).attr('href', firstVideo.url)
    $('#first-video-title').text(firstVideo.snippet.title)
    $('#first-video-description').text(firstVideo.snippet.description)
  });

}


$('#btnSearch').on('click', function() {
   $('#first-video-title').text("")
    if (!apiKey) {
      $('#first-video-title').text("You need to set an apiKey!")
      return;
    }
   gapi.load('client', search)
  });
```

```css
#search-results { white-space: pre; font-family: monospace; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://apis.google.com/js/api.js'></script>

<div id="container">
  <input id="txtSearch" type="text" />
  <button id="btnSearch">
    Search!
  </button>
  <br />
  <p id='first-video-title'> </p>
  <p id='first-video-description'></p>
  <a target="_blank" id="first-video"></a>
  <div id='search-results'>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For anyone who comes across this question and needs something in a browser, this actually worked quite well.